# How to calculate the height of centre of mass above an inclined plane

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

I am attaching the problem here:
[image]

[image]

Since I want to use the energy approach I must require the height of the centre of mass of the rod at the initial and required (angle $\phi$) position.

For the vertical position if I take $h1$ as the height then I get cos$\alpha$ = h1/(a+x) where x is the extension of the rod that meets the base of inclined plane.

How do I calculate the other Height (at $\phi$)?

Comment: $m\ddot y = a\left(\cos(\phi)\ddot\phi-\sin(\phi)\dot\phi^2\right)=R-m g\cos(\alpha)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering a referential with origin at $A$ and rotated for $\alpha$ clockwise, the work done by gravity is

$$
U_{\alpha}=m g(a - a \sin\phi)
$$

and in the inertial frame we have

$$
U = U_{\alpha}\cos\alpha = m g a \cos\alpha(1-\sin\phi)
$$